# How to debug this java code? The code is designed to get the CPU usage and memory info in the Linux System

Tags: java, linux, debugging, snmp, snmp4j

This is a java code I search from the internet: http://avery-leo.iteye.com/blog/298724

Its goal is to get the CPU usage and memory info in the Linux System. I compiled it in eclipse and found two errors as follows:

```
private Config config=Config.getInstance();
SnmpUtil util=new SnmpUtil();
```

which I also mark in bold in the note part.

I think these two errors are caused by the lack of class `Config` and `SnmpUtil`, I tried to search and download a config.jar from the Internet and add it to the lib, but still it does not work!! I need your help!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.net.InetAddress;  
import java.util.StringTokenizer;  

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  

/** 
 * To get the cpu usage and memory in Linux system
 *  
 * <p> 
 */  
public final class LinuxSystemTool implements Runnable{  
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LinuxSystemTool.class);  
    private Config config=Config.getInstance();  //**Error when compiled**
    /** 
     * get memory by used info 
     *  
     * @return int[] result 
     *                      
     * result.length==4; int[0]=MemTotal;int[1]=MemFree；                  
     * int[2]=SwapTotal；int[3]=SwapFree; 
     * @throws IOException    
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */  
public void run() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    while (true) {  

        try {  
            exec();  
            Thread.sleep(config.getThreadTime());  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            log.error("Performance Monitoring error:"+e.getMessage());  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}  
public void exec() throws Exception {  
//      ServerStatus ss = new ServerStatus();  

    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();  
    System.out.println("Performance Monitoring ip:"+inet.toString());  

    String ip=inet.toString().substring(inet.toString().indexOf("/")+1);  
    log.info("Performance Monitoring ip:"+ip);  

    int[] memInfo = LinuxSystemTool.getMemInfo();  
    System.out.println("MemTotal：" + memInfo[0]);  
    System.out.println("MemFree：" + memInfo[1]);  

    SnmpUtil util=new SnmpUtil();  //**Error when compiled**
    util.setCPU(getCpuInfo());  
//  util.setDISK(1);  
    util.setMEM(memInfo[0]/memInfo[1]);  
    util.setIP(ip);  

}  
public static int[] getMemInfo() throws IOException, InterruptedException {  
    File file = new File("/proc/meminfo");  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
            new FileInputStream(file)));  
    int[] result = new int[4];  
    String str = null;  
    StringTokenizer token = null;  
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        token = new StringTokenizer(str);  
        if (!token.hasMoreTokens())  
            continue;  

        str = token.nextToken();  
        if (!token.hasMoreTokens())  
            continue;  

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("MemTotal:"))  
            result[0] = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
        else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("MemFree:"))  
            result[1] = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
        else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("SwapTotal:"))  
            result[2] = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
        else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("SwapFree:"))  
            result[3] = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    }  

    return result;  
}  

/** 
 * get memory by used info 
 *  
 * @return float efficiency 
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */  
public static float getCpuInfo() throws IOException, InterruptedException {  
    File file = new File("/proc/stat");  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
            new FileInputStream(file)));  
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());  
    token.nextToken();  
    int user1 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    int nice1 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    int sys1 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    int idle1 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  

    Thread.sleep(1000);  

    br = new BufferedReader(  
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));  
    token = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());  
    token.nextToken();  
    int user2 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    int nice2 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    int sys2 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  
    int idle2 = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());  

    return (float) ((user2 + sys2 + nice2) - (user1 + sys1 + nice1))  
            / (float) ((user2 + nice2 + sys2 + idle2) - (user1 + nice1  
                    + sys1 + idle1));  
}  

/** 
 *  
 * <p> 
 *  
 * @author 
 * </p> 
 * @date 
 */  

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    int[] memInfo = LinuxSystemTool.getMemInfo();  
    System.out.println("MemTotal：" + memInfo[0]);  
    System.out.println("MemFree：" + memInfo[1]);  
    System.out.println("SwapTotal：" + memInfo[2]);  
    System.out.println("SwapFree：" + memInfo[3]);  

    System.out.println("CPU use ratio：" + LinuxSystemTool.getCpuInfo());  
}  
}
```

Comment: If the compiler says those classes are missing - those classes are just missing...

Comment: The point it how can I get those missing class?

Comment: You need snmp4j library for the system info management.

Answer (score 3):

You need snmp4j jar for snmp related java development. you can get if from [here](http://www.snmp4j.org/).

Hope this will work for you.